# Getting part of a string using REGEX

Tags: php, regex

I have an Amazon link:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Pampers-Softcare-Fresh-Wipes-Count/dp/B007KXO998/ref=pd_zg_rss_ts_165796011_165796011_7?ie=UTF8&tag=elson06-20
```

I'm trying to get the product ID `B007FHX9OK` that is after `dp/` and before `?ref=pd_zg_rss_ts_165796011_165796011_7`
I want to get that using a regex or anything that can extract it.

The link of the url is static, it will not changed.

Comment: something like this dp/(.*)?SubscriptionId=

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I did, since I'm pretty sure that the link has always the same format:

```
$link = 'http://www.amazon.com/Pampers-Softcare-Fresh-Wipes-Count/dp/B007KXO998/ref=pd_zg_rss_ts_165796011_165796011_7?ie=UTF8&tag=elson06-20'
$link = parse_url($link);
$link = explode('/',$link['path']);
$link = $link[3];
echo $link; //B007KXO998
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = 'http://www.amazon.com/iOttie-Windshield-INCREDIBLE-BlackBerry-Revolution/dp/B007FHX9OK?SubscriptionId=AKIAJJPPYQPVMQLOYLKQ&tag=elson06-20&linkCode=sp1&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B007FHX9OK';
//$string = 'http://www.amazon.com/Pampers-Softcare-Fresh-Wipes-Count/dp/B007KXO998/ref=pd_zg_rss_ts_165796011_165796011_7?ie=UTF8&tag=elson06-20';

$pid = basename((false !== strpos($string, '/ref='))
    ? pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)
    : parse_url($string, PHP_URL_PATH));

echo $pid; // Outputs B007KXO998 or B007FHX9OK, will work for both types of URLs
```

You don't need a regex, PHP has built-in functions to parse URLs.

Comment: Wow! that's so fast! I didn't know we can use that one. I'm still testing it on every possible links I have here.

Comment: This assumes that the path will always be in the same format, and that the product id will always be the last portion of the path portion. Amazon uses a bunch of different paths, and the product id isn't always the last section of the path.

Comment: @AgentConundrum if you are right then even a regex would not be reliable as it could change as well where `dp/` may not precede the product ID.

Comment: Sometimes the link becomes like this:
http://www.amazon.com/Pampers-Softcare-Fresh-Wipes-Count/dp/B007KXO998/ref=pd_zg_rss_ts_165796011_165796011_7?ie=UTF8&tag=elson06-20

Comment: @crypticツ I tried your code, but it does not output as expected

Comment: @ElsonSolano see update, will work for both URLs without needing a regex. Amazon has URLs where the id is the last part in the path or 2nd to last, this will grab it regardless of which URL you use.

Comment: @crypticツ I will try it out. Thanks you very much for the effort! very much appreciated! :)

Comment: @ElsonSolano did this not work for you? Works for me and is the efficient way to grab the string using the proper built-in PHP functions. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) there are multiple formats but two distinct areas where the ID is located in the path. The last or 2nd to last, so there is no reason to have to use a regex and loop, let alone two of them to retrieve the value, when the same exact thing can be done accurately with this code without incurring unnecessary overhead. I'm just curious as to the reason for your decision. =o)

Comment: For this url it is not work http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00JZWQW4C/ref=s9_al_gw_g147_i3/176-6229408-1209658?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1Y1FV95EWP1CWWDBH95F&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1976211242&pf_rd_i=507846

Answer (score 0):

Will the URLs always be in this exact format, or will it be expected to match any Amazon URL?

If the format will always be like this, then you can use @cryptic's answer. Otherwise, it would be more flexible to use a pattern like `|dp/([A-Z0-9]+)|i` for the pattern.

This will match any alphanumeric string (case insensitive) directly following `dp/` in the string. Well, the entire match will include the `dp/` part, but the parenthetical portion is a sub-match which will match only the product id.

---

Edit: According to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number), Amazon's product IDs (ASINs) can be present in a wide variety of URLs, making them difficult to match, and my code above won't catch them all.

One way to try to catch these would be to use `parse_url` to extract the `host` and the `path` portions of the URL. From there, you can check the host portion against known Amazon domain names, and you could `explode` the path, and check each portion for an alphanumeric section which is ten characters long. Even then, the ASIN for books is the books ISBN, and there are 13-digit versions which Amazon might use in some cases (though I don't have evidence that they do).

Here is a very basic example that I haven't thoroughly tested:

```
$url = get_url_from_wherever();
$url_parts = parse_url($url);

$host = $url_parts['host'];
$path = explode('/', $url_parts['path']);

$amazon_hosts = array(
   'amazon.com',   // United States
   'amazon.ca',    // Canada
   'amazon.cn',    // China
   'amazon.fr',    // France
   'amazon.it',    // Italy
   'amazon.de',    // Germany
   'amazon.es',    // Spain
   'amazon.co.jp', // Japan
   'amazon.co.uk', // United Kingdom
   'amzn.to'       // URL Shortener
);
$amazon_hosts = array_map('preg_quote', $amazon_hosts);

$asin = FALSE; // initialize in case we don't find the ASIN

if (preg_match('/(^|\.)(' . implode($amazon_hosts, '|') . ')$/i', $host)) {
  // valid host
  foreach($path as $path_component) {
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]{10}$/i', $path_component)) {
      // this is probably the ASIN, since the string is a 10-character alphanumeric
      $asin = $path_component;
    }
  }
}

if ($asin) {
  // process ASIN
} else {
  // couldn't find an ASIN in this URL
}
```

Comment: The answer on your question is it will match any Amazon URL. I want to get the product id. i'm absolutely noob in Regex, can you show me how to do that one? Thanks! :)

Comment: @ElsonSolano This is what the pattern in my answer already does, under the assumption that it's always directly after `dp/`, which is apparently a bad assumption - [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) shows many different URL forms. I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: As of now, let's just put the assumption that it is always after dp/ ad before ?SubscriptionId=

Comment: @crypticツ I pasted another link, I think I pasted the wrong link, that's why I changed it. I'm pretty sure that the link format is static or it won't changed.

Comment: @ElsonSolano I updated my answer with a more thorough, but probably still insufficient, code sample. There are probably edge cases I'm not aware of, but this code passed the tests I threw at it.